# Installing USB Mouse on NF61S Micro AM2 SE?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb, usb-2

I am using Windows XP sp3 and Windows 7 on NF61S Micro AM2 SE motherboard with AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4400+, 2.31Ghz, 1.93RAM

link for motherboard site;
http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=23#dl

My problems are..
1. When I try to install usb 2.0 drivers from motherboard CD its prompt me to install XP sp2 but XP is alrady sp3? When trying to install sp2 its says sp3 already installed.

2. Various usb device malfunction on this system, like IT-OP81 JASHAN usb optical mouse which is working fine on my laptop on XP Win 7 both, but not working on this machine, system says usb device not recognized, when i use usb to ps2 converter and connect on ps2 port mouse works on this machine, other usb optical mouse is working on this machine?